# Creating draggable objects with Quartz Framework on Image and exporting. - iOS

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics

I'm actually looking for a simple thing here..

I've got an image over ImageView, Want to place and Arrow and a label over a specific part of that image. (so its gotta be draggable).

Put multiple such arrows with labels and finally export it to a new Image on iPhone.

First saw it actually on an app called Photogene,

I actually have little information about quartz framework. So any thing/sample pointing my to a github repo/ help would be great..